# How to program a pressure sensor using the SPI Bus

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, spi, lora

I am using the STM32 Microcontroller (as part of the LoRa node MB1296D). I want to connect a pressure sensor (MS5803) to the LoRa node and program the sensor via the SPI Bus. Basically, this is all very new to me, which is why I looked up an [example code](https://www.parallax.com/sites/default/files/downloads/29124-APPNote_520_C_code.pdf)

I am trying to understand this code and a couple of questions have come up:

- the macros that are defined in the very beginning, what exactly is their purpose, and are the hexadecimal numbers inherent to the used microcontroller? - If I was to write a code from scratch, I figured I would start by defining macros for the GPIO Pins corresponding to SPI_SCK, SPI_MISO and SPI_MOSI
- the function `unsigned long cmd_adc(char cmd)` contains a switch command, which I have absolutely no clue as on what is does. I mean it looks to me as if I am trying to set the resolution of the ADC, but how do I know the corresponding delay and why does the switch command contain the 0x0f ?

So. If you could find some time to give me a useful answer, that'd be great! Also, if you know any good readings with special focus on this topic, please tell me! I am trying to tackle this problem with little time available.

Comment: Rather than diving straight into some big ball of example code, I would suggest studying the datasheet for the part and understanding the commands it accepts and how it responds. Any code will make more sense when you understand how the protocol to the part operates and you will be in a better position to tailor the operation to your requirements. Just because you are short on time doesn't mean that beating on example code is the quickest path.

Comment: If you have never done SPI or I2C and particularly if you dont have a multi-channel scope, you are going to struggle, period and going to struggle more trying to use canned libraries that talk to a peripheral.  if you bit bang the protocol which is pretty easy you at least have more control over the state changes without having more visibility than that, and have some sort of a chance.  any time you take on a hardware peripheral that does the work for you you really need a scope or need to slow the signals down to  human speed and....

Comment: have a handful of leds to blink.   and you still have to read the datasheet for the part you are trying to talk to so you can build the waveforms required to communicate, chip select, clock, mosi (master out slave in) miso (master in slave out, sometimes somi sometimes just D2 or some name like that).   I2c is even worse as you have a bidirectional data line (can have that with spi too but not seen that often)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions are basic C programming questions and are not really specific to this pressure sensor or example.

The macros are defined with hexadecimal numbers to make it clear that the values represent bit fields.  It's very easy (and second nature for embedded software developers) to convert hexadecimal to binary.  Read the register descriptions in the sensor's datasheet.  The bits set in the hexadecimal values will correspond to meaningful bits in the sensor's register description.

`switch (cmd & 0x0f)` performs a bitwise AND of the `cmd` with `0x0f`.  The hexadecimal value `0x0f` has the four least significant bits set.  So the code is ignoring (i.e., masking off or zeroing out) the four most significant bits of `cmd` and considering only the four least significant bits of the `cmd` value.